# Changing column name in table | Power BI

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with 10 columns which is used in power bi table visual, but the column names gets changing.
Which breaks table visual in power bi.
Is there any way that will change the table visual column names on the fly as soon as the report is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

1. Click 'Transform'
2. Click 'Use Headers as First Row'
3. Click 'Use First Row as Headers'

Let me know if this works.